# GridView Textboxes not getting cleared on web tab change

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, infragistics

*I have a Page which has a 2 level web tab . The Content tabs FIXED and VARIABLE in turn has a web tab. This web tab is loaded with a User control which has a gridview.
My problem is the textboxes in the Gridview are not cleared on going from one sub tab to next sub tab . I tried all possible methods : 
1.Bind grid to null ( datasource and DatasoruceId )
2. grid dispose
3. grid columns clear 
No luck !!!.. HELP!!!
Note : I am modifying the data in the textboxes from javascript.*

```
<ig:Webtab id="wi" runat="server" width="938px" displaymode="Scrollable" meta:resourcekey="wtabInvestmentTypeResource1">
                                <ClientEvents SelectedIndexChanging="webTab_SelectedIndexChanging" />
                                <AutoPostBackFlags SelectedIndexChanged="On" />
                                <Tabs>
                                    <ig:ContentTabItem runat="server" Text="Variable Investment Type" meta:resourcekey="ContentTabItemResource1">
                                        <Template>
                                            <div class="clear vspacesmall hspacenarrow">
                                            </div>
                                            <ig:WebTab ID="wv" runat="server" Width="908px" DisplayMode="Scrollable" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                meta:resourcekey="wtabVariableResource1">
                                                <ClientEvents SelectedIndexChanging="webTab_SelectedIndexChanging" />
                                                <AutoPostBackFlags SelectedIndexChanged="On" />     
                                            </ig:WebTab>
                                        </Template>
                                    </ig:ContentTabItem>
                                    <ig:ContentTabItem runat="server" Text="Fixed Investment Type" meta:resourcekey="ContentTabItemResource2">
                                        <Template>
                                            <div class="clear vspacesmall hspacenarrow">
                                            </div>
                                            <ig:WebTab ID="wf" runat="server" Width="908px" DisplayMode="Scrollable" class="tabs"
                                                meta:resourcekey="wtabFixedResource1">
                                                <ClientEvents SelectedIndexChanging="webTab_SelectedIndexChanging" />
                                                <AutoPostBackFlags SelectedIndexChanged="On" />
                                            </ig:WebTab>
```

The web tab loads a user control which has the following gridview :

```
  <div class="clear vspacesmall gridtablearea scrollPanel-horizontal Contol-Max-Height">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upBuyMultipleGetDiscount" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvInvestmentDetails" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvInvestmentDetails_RowDataBound"
                            TabIndex="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="gridtable scrollPanel-horizontal" Width="100%" meta:resourcekey="gvInvestmentDetails_DefaultResource1"
                           EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ShowFooter="true" OnRowCommand="gvInvestmentDetails_Row_Command">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="InvestmentTypeId" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerCombinationId" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductId" />

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account"  ItemStyle-Width="100px" meta:resourcekey="Account">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAccountName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerCombinationName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Products" ItemStyle-Width="200px" meta:resourcekey="Products">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" CssClass="fRight boldText" ForeColor="#656565" runat="server" Text='TOTAL :' meta:resourcekey="lblTotal"></asp:Label>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phase Investment Amount"  meta:resourcekey="PhaseInvestmentAmount" >
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrPhases" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  OnDataBinding="rptrPhases_OnDataBinding">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <div style="float: left; padding: 4px;">
                                                <table id="PhaseDetails">
                                                <tr>
                                                     <td>
                                                     <tr>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPhaseID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhaseID") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>                                               
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPhaseName" Class="vspacesmall" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhaseName") %>' ></asp:Label><br />
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhaseAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhaseAmount", "{0:F2}") %>'  CssClass="tar"
                                                        ClientIDMode="Static" Width="80px" MaxLength="27" onpaste="return false;"  ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                                                        meta:resourcekey="txtPhaseAmount"></asp:TextBox>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                   <asp:Label ID="lblUsageAmount" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("PhaseUpdateAmount", "{0:F2}") %>'></asp:Label> 
                                                    </tr>
                                                   </td>
                                                   </tr>
                                                   </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptTotalAmount" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                             <div style="float: left; padding: 4px;">
                                             <table>
                                             <tr>
                                             <td>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhaseTotal" Text='<%# Eval("PhaseAmount", "{0:F2}") %>' Width="80px" CssClass="tar boldText" 
                                                    ForeColor="#656565" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ClientIdMode="Static"  autocomplete="off"  ></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </ItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roles" ItemStyle-Width="150px"   meta:resourcekey="Roles">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chckRoleList"  runat="server" DataTextField="RoleName"  
                                            DataValueField="RoleId" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  onclick="checkBoxLstChanged(this.id,'chkSelectAll');SetIsChanged('1');">
                                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbRoleList" runat="server" DataTextField="RoleName" 
                                            DataValueField="RoleId" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chckSelectAll" runat="server" Text="Select All" onclick="setAllCheckBoxes('chckRoleList',this);SetIsChanged('1');" meta:resourcekey="chckSelectAll">
                                        </asp:CheckBox>
                                        <br>
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnRemove" runat="server" CssClass="btnStyle fLeft" Text="Remove" OnClientClick="return ValidateRemoveRoles('gvInvestmentDetails')"
                                             CommandName="RemoveRoles" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                                              meta:resourcekey="btnRemove"  />
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="InvestmentAmount" meta:resourcekey="InvestmentAmount">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtInvAmt" Width="80px" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InvestmentAmount","{0:F2}") %>'
                                           ClientIdMode="Static"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" CssClass="fRight tar  boldText" ></asp:TextBox >
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalInvestment" ClientIdMode="Static" Width="80px" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  CssClass="fRight tar boldText "   ForeColor="#656565" runat="server" />
                                    </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                     <asp:BoundField DataField="RecordStatus"  />
                            </Columns>
                           <%-- <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="boldText" ForeColor="#656565" />--%>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

The back end code for loading the USer control :

```
 private void LoadInvestmentDetails(int investmentTypeId, WebTab currentWebTab, int tabIndex)
        {
            Panel panel = GetPanelToBeLoaded(investmentTypeId);

            if (currentWebTab.Tabs[tabIndex].Controls.Count == 0)
            {

                    currentWebTab.Tabs[tabIndex].Controls.Add(panel);
                    budgetDetailsControl.Initialize(investmentTypeId);
                    budgetDetailsControl.InvestmentDetailsSaved += new ProjectInvestmentDetailsSavedEventHandler(BudgetDetailsControl_BudgetDetailsSaved);
                    PreviouslyLoadedTab = int.Parse(currentWebTab.Tabs[currentWebTab.SelectedIndex].UserControlUrl);


            }
      // other code 
         }



    private Panel GetPanelToBeLoaded(int investmentTypeId)
    {
        System.Web.UI.Control userControl = GetInvestmentDetailsUserControlUrl();
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.Controls.Add(userControl);
        budgetDetailsControl = (IProjectInvestmentDetailsControl)userControl;
        budgetDetailsControl.InvestmentTypeID = investmentTypeId;
        return panel;
    }


        private System.Web.UI.Control GetInvestmentDetailsUserControlUrl()
        {
            return LoadControl(ProjectCommonKeys.URL_PROJECT_BUDGET_DETAILS);
        }
```

The Usercontrol implments the IprojectInvestmentDetails interface and the initalize function of the UC is called first for the binding etc

Comment: I believe more information is needed to answer what is happening.  If I have understood correctly you have two tabs in either WebTab with id of wv or wf and they load the same UserControl.  Since these tabs aren't defined in the markup I assume you are adding the tabs and user controls dynamically.  I would need details on that logic since if that is the case then then you would also need to be dynamically creating the user controls on each post back (which happens on the tab change).  I would also want to know what events you have used in your testing when clearing the textboxes.

Comment: When you say that the textboxes don't clear, do you mean that you expect a new gridview with empty textboxes to appear on tab change?  Or is changing tabs supposed to cause the previous tab to discard its data and (if returned to) show empty textboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Each user control bound to the sub tab shud be given a unique Id..or else even if we bind new data the data from the earlier instance will persist.

.

```
private Panel GetPanelToBeLoaded(int investmentTypeId)
        {
            System.Web.UI.Control userControl = GetInvestmentDetailsUserControlUrl();
            **userControl.ID = investmentTypeId.ToString();**
            Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.Controls.Add(userControl);
            projectInvestmentDetailsControl = (IProjectInvestmentDetailsControl)userControl;
            projectInvestmentDetailsControl.InvestmentTypeID = investmentTypeId;
            projectInvestmentDetailsControl.UserContext = userContext;
            projectInvestmentDetailsControl.PlanningWizardDataManager = PlanningWizardDataManager;
            projectInvestmentDetailsControl.PlanningServiceWrapper = PlanningServiceWrapper;

            return panel;
        }`
```

Thanks fr the help...